# Modalpopupextender with usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I am using different user controls with Modalpopupextender (within page, repeater etc.) and it took some time to figure all the tricks how to get this two togeather.

I have now ended up with the following problem

When I pass a param into user control

```
UserControl.ParamID = 1;
```

I am able to receive it in user control, but at the strange step of page cycle.

When I try to do

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     throw new Exception(ParamID);
}
```

I get null for ParamID!?

But when I do

```
<% throw new Exception(ParamID); %>
```

from html, I get a correct ParamID value.

I tryied to store ParamID as ViewState, as a HiddeField, and it is always doing the same error.

Also, when I use this user control wihout mpe, just in regular aspx page, it all works just fine.

What is the catch?